# Load file on Tomcat Server (JSF,SPRING)

Tags: java, file, tomcat, maven, load

Somebody here who knows how to load a file on the tomcat server?
We are using:
Maven, JSF 2, Spring 3, Tomcat 7

I have the following Project Structure:

[image: structure]

I want to load the page.xml file!

I thought about setting a Environment Variable in the GlobalNamingResource in the server.xml of the server. But how can I access this variable in my WebApp?

Or I can use the ContextClassLoader, but if I want to load that file, I always get back null.

The problem is, that I can not use the FacesContext, because i get back null if I call FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

Currently I had to hardcode the path to get it work. But I always have to change this path if I want to test it in eclipse or if I deploy it on the server.

```
@PostConstruct
public void loadMenu() {
             List<Page> pageCollection = new ArrayList<Page>();
    Page page = null;

    File xmlFile = new File(
            "C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 7.0\\webapps\\rainstar2-webapp\\WEB-INF\\classes\\at\\beko\\rainstar2\\page.xml");

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDoc = db.parse(xmlFile);
        xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList pages = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("page");
        int size = pages.getLength();
        Node pageNode = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            pageNode = pages.item(i);
            NamedNodeMap attr = pageNode.getAttributes();
            page = new Page();
            page.setLabel(attr.getNamedItem("key").getNodeValue()
                    .toString());
            page.setRedirect(Boolean.valueOf(attr.getNamedItem("redirect")
                    .getNodeValue().toString()));
            page.setNavigationName(attr.getNamedItem("url").getNodeValue()
                    .toString());
            page.addRole(attr.getNamedItem("role").getNodeValue()
                    .toString());
            pageCollection.add(page);
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be good you post the code that you used to load the xml for us to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JSF you could use the [ResourceHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html). It works nice for resources under `/webapp/resources`. I am not entirely sure about resources under `/main`

```
    FacesContext currentContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ResourceHandler resourceHandler = currentContext.getApplication()
            .getResourceHandler();
    Resource resource = resourceHandler.createResource(fileName, libraryName);
```

The `libraryName` is the name of the folder under `/webapp/resources`.

EDIT : Without relying on JSF you could use the good old [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).

```
     InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()  
             .getResourceAsStream("/path/to/file/from/.war_as_root/fileName");
```

Please note that the path is relative from the root of your packaged .war

Comment: Ok that sounds very nice! The only problem is that I have a method in the JavaBean that is anotated with @PostConstruct and if I want to get the current instance of the FacesContext with FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() in that method , I only get back null. Is there no way without using the FacesContext?

Comment: @Matthias Have edited the answer adding a classloader-based alternative

Comment: Thank you! I had nearly the same solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok My solution was.

I put  the the page.xml into the web-inf.

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL url = loader.getResource("..\\page.xml");
    File xmlFile = null;
    try {
        xmlFile = new File(url.toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image]